# Как сделать групповое конвертирование всех файлов в в директории

Tags: ubuntu

Всем добрый день не могу найти решение группового конвертирования всех файлов в директории. По мануалу конвертирую один файл, но у меня их сотни и они в одной директории назовем ее "папка".

Установил необходимое ПО:

```
sudo apt-get install djvulibre-bin
```

сконвертировал книгу:

```
ddjvu -format=pdf Названиефайла.{djvu,pdf}
```

Comment: Попробуйте такое: ``for i in *.djvu; do  ddjvu -format=pdf $i.{djvu,pdf}; done`` (только сначала в отдельной папочке с парой файлов).

Comment: @Эникейщик, очевидно, что не сработает: будет искать файлы `.djvu.djvu`... да ещё и веселья наловишь, если в именах есть пробелы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.djvu' | while read f; do
   ddjvu -format=pdf "$f" "${f%.djvu}.pdf"
done
```

#### Краткое описание:

`find` ищет в текущем каталоге файлы по шаблону `*.djvu`, затем скармливает их список циклу `while`, который на каждой итерации читает имя файла в переменную `f`. Конструкция `${f%.djvu}` отрезает у переменной `f` суффикс `.djvu`, а дальше строка дополняется `.pdf`, чтобы получить имя выходного файла.

#### Ограничения:

Не сработает, если в именах файлов есть символы перевода строки.